# Conda set default environment

Tags: conda, miniconda

I've just started with using conda (miniconda) for managing different python environments. By default there is a "base" environment. To seperate development from specific projects I've created a new environment called "development" in which I've installed a list of packages.

Whenever I start up my laptop (windows) it uses the "base" environment by default and I have to manually activate the development environment. Is there a way to set the default environment different than the "base" environment, such that I don't have to start with "activate development" whenever I start up my laptop?

I already tried by adding the path to the environment to the user PATH variable under windows before other paths. This however hasn't helped.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why not just use the base environment? (I don't think there is a way to change the default environment, FWIW)

Comment: Because there might be a project where I need a package that is only available for python 2.7 for example.

Comment: Then why not create a Python 2.7 environment?

Comment: Because python3 also has its benefits. Simply said, there can be a situation in which one environment needs to be used and a situation where another needs to be used. If you would like to know why you would use different environments I suggest you read: https://medium.com/the-python-corner/using-virtual-environments-with-python-7166d3bfa218

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm suggesting... Use different environments for different purposes. If you mostly use a Python 3 environment, then set that as your base by installing Anaconda3 and install all your necessary packages there and create a separate Python 2 environment. Otherwise, install Anaconda 2 with all of your necessary packages and a separate Python 3 environment. I still don't understand why you want to change the default environment...

Comment: Because I feel that using a base environment by default will quickly clutter the situation. Pycharm btw support a environment for a project so that works fine.

Comment: I use a bash alias to make switching to my general dev fast: put `alias sab='source activate basePy3'` in your ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 2):

If you start from anaconda prompt, you can change the property of the shortcut.
Change the end of it's target from:

```
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\
```

to:

```
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\env\yourenv
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the default Anaconda Prompt, You can launch another Anaconda Prompt which activates corresponding env for you. For example, the 'myEnv' Anaconda Prompt, which is installed automatically when you create a new env called 'myEnv'. [image]